# Difference when declaring a DataSource in markup compared to code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

I have a legacy solution where all the `DataSource`s are defined in the markup for all .aspx-pages. The problem I have with this is that the `DataSource` get instantiated several times since it is used in page, control... What I want is to have NInject to handle the instantiation of the `DataSource` so this doesn't happen. I have got that part to sort of work, but when the `DataSource` is defined in the code-behind instead of in the markup the `Page` property is not set on the `DataSource`, does anyone know why?

A simple solution to this is to set the the `Page` property in a base class or something, but I do think that the property should be there and want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `DataBind()` after you set it.

```
WebControl1.DataSource = something;
WebControl1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is probably useful for others, but it is not what I was asking for. I asked for why the `Page` property is not set.

Comment: This was probably part of the solution, I'm not 100 % sure how I solved it but I might have used the actual `DataSource` when setting the `DataSource` property instead of just one method in the `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

It may has to do with the point in time of instantiation in the page lifecycle? Can you monitor (debug) the instantiation in the code behind? Which callback are you using in the code behind? If you are using the controls code behind, the Page property may not be set yet than. So choose a later callback - after the control has been added to some page already.

Comment: I tried to instantiate the control in `PreInit` of the page and it to the page `Control` collection, but it didn't help. I ended up writing my own `DataSource` base class that overrides the `Page` property and look it up from the current `HttpContext`.